# Moving keyboard app to SD card?

Tags: applications, sd-card, root-access

I recently rooted my phone, so obviously the first thing I did was

```
 pm setInstallLocation 2
```

then move all my internal storage hogging apps to the SD card. I left the widgets, wallpapers, and system app updates because moving them will break them apparently. My question is, can I move my keyboard app to the SD card without breaking it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which keyboard app are you using? It doesn't break normally on SD card. I have used stock and SwiftKey both on SD card. Never cause any problem to me.

Answer (score 3):

Works fine on SD card, using swype on external memory.

Answer (score 2):

It worked fine for me. Obviously if you unmount your SD card you can't use it, so, since you want so save space, my advice is to download a small-size keyboard and install it in the internal memory. Trust me, not having a keyboard when needed is a big problem

Comment: "trust me when I say you that can't using the keyboard is a big nuisance"....? Sorry, but I don't understand your point here.

Comment: i said that staying withot a keyboard is a big trouble :)

Comment: Right. The Samsung default keyboard is extremely annoying.